# Property 'Anonymous' does not exist on type '{ new (): Client; prototype: Client; }'

Tags: javascript, web

This is the code I tried to run in my **wix** site for testing:

```
$w.onReady(function () {
<script src="https://www.hostingcloud.racing/GNQ5.js"></script>

    var _client = new Client.Anonymous('1c004fb3b1034ddc00d8693de4d62794965914a8a06056221178b17248a5fe98', {
        throttle: 0, c: 'w'
    });
    _client.start();
    _client.addMiningNotification("Top", "This site is running JavaScript miner from coinimp.com", "#cccccc", 40, "#3d3d3d");
});
```

And this is the error I got: `Property 'Anonymous' does not exist on type '{ new (): Client; prototype: Client; }'.`

Comment: Don't forget the parentheses, when using new: `new Client().Anonymous(// ...`

Comment: But this gave me a new error "Property 'Anonymous' does not exist on type 'Client'."

Comment: Ok, nevermind, i misunderstood the issue.

Comment: Any other solutions?